# Get error for using nms, : 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, fastlane-match

My code is:

```
keep, num_to_keep, _ = nms(proposals, scores, overlap=nms_thres, top_k=nms_topk)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\RaSoul\LaneATT\lib\models\laneatt.py", line 129, in nms
    keep, num_to_keep, _ = nms(proposals, scores, overlap=nms_thres, top_k=nms_topk)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm confused with the error, why is that?

Comment: Please read [mre]. We have no idea what `nms` function you’re trying to call. All import statements must be included for us to understand that.

Comment: How did you import that `nms` name? Which library is it from?

Comment: You cannot use the brackets because it is not a function data type, but a ```module``` object. So, maybe you cannot put parameters in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `nms` is a function defined in `nms.py` file.
When importing `nms`:

```py
import nms
```

You import all functions in the file `nms.py` into the "scope" `nms`. Therefore, you should call the function `nms` defined in `nms.py` like this:

```py
keep, num_to_keep, _ = nms.nms(proposals, scores, overlap=nms_thres, top_k=nms_topk)
```

Alternatively, you can import the specific function `nms` from `nms.py`:

```py
from nms import nms
```

This will put the `nms` function in the global "scope" and you will not need to call it with `nms.nms(...)`, but rather use simply `nms(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.... I've done this importing nms from nms but I still get this error.